# How to make a search functionality that contains more than one word in ASP MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, search

I have a **model** class, which contains

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

In the **controller** I have

```
 public ActionResult Index(string search)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contacts.";

            var model = _db.Contacts
                        .OrderBy(c => c.FirstName)
                        .Where(c => search == null || c.FirstName.StartsWith(search) || c.LastName.StartsWith(search))
                        .Take(5)
                        .Select(c => new ContactsListViewModel
                        {
                            ContactId = c.ContactId,
                            FirstName = c.FirstName,
                            LastName = c.LastName,
                            Address = c.Address,
                            City = c.City,
                            Phone = c.Phone,
                            Email = c.Email

                        });



            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_Contacts", model);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

So far I managed to make search by first name and last name separately.
For example, if I enter John I get all information related to John nicely. Same with Last Name.
So I have a question how I can implement a search functionality, so that users can enter, for example first name and last name in one input form and related table will appear?

Help is very appreciated. Thanks

Thanks, Raphaël Althaus for your answer. But I already have a search form in my view

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")"
    data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#contactList">
    <input type="search" name="search" data-otf-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete", "Contacts")" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

It seems, that you offrer is to search first name and last name in separate textboxes. But I would like to enter, for example John Doe in one search form and get a table related to that person.
I already have a partial view with tables, which show information only if I enter first name and last name separately.

Comment: Why can't you use `contains i.e. c.FirstName.Contains(search)`? IMHO that will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have little bit changes in your linq query like that .

In my project i am using that' way :

```
var data1 = (from con in dbData.tblPresenters
                             let FillName = con.PresenterFirstName + " " + con.PresenterLastName
                             where FillName.ToLower().Trim().Contains(txtName.Text.Trim().ToLower()) 
                             select new
                             {                                    
                                 FirstName = con.PresenterFirstName,
                                 LastName = con.PresenterLastName,

                             }).ToList();
```

May be this will help you !!

Answer (score 4):

You may use  a class `SearchClass` in your view, which would also contain a `FirstName` and a `LastName` property, and include it in a form.

```
@model SearchClass

@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)

 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
 <input type="submit" value = "search" />
}
```

Then

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SearchClass search) {
   IQueryable<Contact> model = _db.Contacts.AsQueryable();
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.FirstName))
       model = model.Where(m => m.FirstName.StartsWith(search.FirstName));

   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.LastName))
       model = model.Where(m => m.LastName.StartsWith(search.LastName));

   var result = model
            .OrderBy(c => c.FirstName)
            .Take(5)
            //etc.

}
```

Comment: One detail: `var model` must be `IQueryable<Contact>` because `_db.Contacts` is a `DbSet` and `model.Where(..)` is a `DbQuery`. Both implement `IQueryable`, while `var` would be strong typed as `DbSet`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linq-to-entities you could use **String.Concat** to concat the fields of the entities.

```
var searchResult = DbContext.Users
                        .Where(u => String.Concat(u.FirstName, " ", u.LastName)
                        .Contains(searchTerm));
```